# Turn on a device if voltage drops below a configurable level?

Tags: batteries, switching

Consider a Li-Po battery that has to be protected from damage by going below 3V.

What would be the easiest, lightest, smallest ways to e.g. turn on a warning LED or buzzer (using the same battery supply) if the voltage drops below a configurable threshold?

For a single Li-Po a configurable range of 3.0 - 4.0V would make sense, for a 3S Li-Po the range would start at 9.0V.

Comment: you want to turn on an LED or a buzzer so that the battery can be discharged even more? ..... perhaps you may want to disconnect the load from the battery instead

Comment: @jsotola No, they have these for radio-controlled model airplanes where the motor load dominates over any buzzer anyways. It lets the pilot know the battery is running low so they can land before the battery REALLY dies. Of course, in this instance the plane can't save the battery itself simply by disconnecting the battery mid-air and human intervention is required.

Comment: makes sense in that application

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Keep in mind that questions about optimization (i.e., *"What is the best ...?"*) require a definition about what problem dimensions are to be optimized for your application, such as size, speed, energy consumption, user experience, etc. Since these can't be optimized all at once, you need to have a good idea of which ones are most important to you, and be able to articulate that clearly to us.

Comment: @DaveTweed That's why I didn't ask for a "best" solution.

Comment: @jsotola The actual load has to be disconnected manually by the user. The led/buzzer is there to inform the user that the battery is running low.

Answer (score 2):

The zener sets the reference voltage. The pot sets the trigger voltage. In this circuit, if the pot (v-) voltage drops lower than the reference, then the LED turns off. If you want it to turn on, then reverse the V+ and V- terminals to the comparator.

Consider that if this is done with a Li-po, there is a possibility that current will be drawn when the battery is already low, potentially lowering the battery voltage to dangerous levels.

[image]
Source: https://www.electroschematics.com/4004/low-battery-indicator/

Comment: +1 for adjusting the battery input with a divider while using a fixed reference than the other way around (using the divider to adjust the reference).

Comment: I also used a comparator like this to try and detect 110/220V and switch a relay, it only worked 99% of the time, power spikes caused it to switch and that was bad.

Comment: even with hysteresis? and decoupling?

Comment: Yep, decoupling was part of the problem, it had to switch fast or it would burn things out. But there was no way to ride out the transients without lots of decoupling. I worked on it for a month or two, and then finally opted for a 110/220 switch

Comment: Is there an integrated version of this? If not,what would increase precision and lower power draw (a voltage reference IC)?

Comment: @xnor Nothing can be done well, without good specs to define what level is useful and what level is ideal.   Alerts ought to be 10% duty cycle to save power at ~ 1Hz. Detection threshold can be 1% micropower, but alert must be well defined

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 What are you on about? The voltage range is in the question. There is no duty cycle or Hz, this is strictly DC.

Comment: Power consumption?? Save low battery with pulsed indicator , (duty cycle) range of indication? background  noise level ? etc. Why are your requirements not specified very well?  You are simply asking for UVP or undervoltage protection or "low V detection" which is very common but you have a purpose and that is unique to your envirornment. Alert, but not draw excess current. yet be visible or audible